# Is it possible to bulk change the value of cells for grouped rows in slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Could someone tell me please, Is it possible to bulk change the value of cells for grouped rows in slickgrid?
Previously used Silverlight and it was possible.
Thanks.

upd
I apologize for the confusion. The screenshot shows our old datagrid shape in silverlight. So the question is whether there are group controls in the slickgrid that allow you to change the values for the cells of this column in subordinate / grouped rows.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: with your updated question, as far as I know the Grouping Header isn't configurable apart from the title and item count. So I don't think you can add anything else but the title on that grouping header row. It's a header row, not a regular row so there's no cell or anything like it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly but if it's to do bulk change and you use the SlickGrid DataView, you can just start with `beginUpdate` do your changes and call `endUpdate` once you're done and you probably need to call `grid.invalidate()` to re-render the grid with new data. While re-rendering, it should update the grouping at the same time.

Also worth to know that there was this [PR](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/572) which the subject was "Adds optimized bulk operations to DataView" which you can see this [Example - Optimizing DataView Updates](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-optimizing-updates.html)

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.
The screenshot shows our old datagrid shape in silverlight.
So the question is whether there are group controls in the slickgrid that allow you to change the values for the cells of this column in subordinate / grouped rows.
Please check the screenshot https://ibb.co/q7PnRv1

Comment: sorry but I can't open any links on a work laptop, try to update your question instead with an animated gif (you can upload it in your question) or just put a print screen in the question. But anyway, like I said earlier, you can you update the data (lines) and the group will automatically change

Comment: I have updated the main request. Please check it.